# How to trigger Knockout Validation on form field update only

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am currently working on a form that has three fields for user to put in: Report, Hold and Decline. Business rules are, either of them could be null, but if any value put in, then it must be Report < Hold < Decline. Using knockout.validation is pretty good, except whenever I put value in one input box, all the validation will be validated and shown on the page, which is confusing. What I want to do is, if a user enter a Report value, then enter a Decline value, then on the UI, Error message should show under Decline input saying "Decline Value must be more than Report value" if it is the case, but I don't like to see another error message showing under Report input, and vise versa.

[image]

Here is my code:

UI:

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: Report">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputReport">Report</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="inputReport" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: Report"  />
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors error">
        <span data-bind="validationMessage: Report"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: Hold">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputHold">Hold</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="inputHold" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: Hold"/>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors error">
        <span data-bind="validationMessage: Hold"></span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: Decline">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputDecline">Decline</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="inputDecline" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: Decline"/>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors error">
        <span data-bind="validationMessage: Decline"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.Report = ko.observable(null)
.extend({
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    required: false
});

self.Hold = ko.observable(null)
    .extend({
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        required: false
    });
self.Decline = ko.observable(null)
    .extend({
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        required: false
    });

self.Report.extend({
        validation: [
            {
                validator: function(val) {
                    if (self.Hold() && val > self.Hold()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be less than Hold value'
            }, {
                validator: function(val) {
                    if (self.Decline() && val > self.Decline()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be less than Decline value'
            }
        ]
    });


self.Hold.extend({
        validation: [
            {
                validator: function (val) {
                    if (self.Report() && val < self.Report()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be more than Report value'
            }, {
                validator: function (val) {
                    if (self.Decline() && val > self.Decline()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be less than Decline value'
            }
        ]
    });


self.Decline.extend({
        validation: [
            {
                validator: function(val) {
                    if (self.Hold() && val < self.Hold()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be more than Hold value'
            }, {
                validator: function(val) {
                    if (self.Report() && val < self.Report()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                message: 'Must be less than Report value'
            }
        ]
    });
 }

ko.validation.init({
   insertMessages: false,
   decorateElement: true,
   errorElementClass: 'has-error',
   errorMessageClass: 'help-inline'
 },true);


$(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new LimitManagerAdminViewModel());
 });
```

In the Anonymous validators, I tried to check for isModified on Report, Hold and Decline, and no matter what they are always true. If somebody can show me how to show the message for just the input user works on(when tab out of it), that'd be fantastic.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: IMO the user __should__ be shown both the `validation` messages because suppose the user has just entered `2` as an input for `Report` and at this moment suppose `Decline` has a value of `1`, so the user has now a choice as to either increase the value of `Decline` to greater than that of `Report` or decrease the value of `Report` to less than that of `Decline`. Thoughts?

Comment: @gkb: Thanks for your comments. I understood what you were saying, however that's not our desired behavior. The desire is that user focus on the field that he/she is editing. Thanks for your help.